# Error in C#: Not all code path return a value

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working in C#.

I have a connection string and I am fetching the details

```
class CustomerSummaries
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetAll", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            SqlDataReader sdr;
            conn.Open();
            sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                if (sdr.IsDBNull(sdr.GetOrdinal("ContactName")) != true)
                {
                    sdr["ContactName"].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
            //lblErrorMsg.Visible = true;
            //lblErrorMsg.Text += "<br><b>getProjectLead_Error: </b> " + ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    } 
}
```

I am getting an error that says Not all code path return a value, how could fix my code?

Answer (score 2):

Your function declaration says you're going to return an `IEnumerable<T>`, but there is no `return` statement.

Furthermore, `T` is not a data type. I think you're going to have a bad time with that.

I also notice that `sdr["ContactName"].ToString();` doesn't really do anything--it doesn't modify the column value because it's a function, not a method, and you're not assigning the result of the function to a variable to do something further with it.

Comment: I can't tell you what you should be doing, only you know that. Ask a new question, stating what you want to accomplish, and provide enough code so we can understand the context. What kind of list do you want to return from your function?

Comment: Good point! IEnumerable here is my controller:public class CustomerSummaryController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /CustomerSummary/
        private CustomerSummaries _customerSummaries = new CustomerSummaries();

        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            IEnumerable<CustomerSummary> summaries = _customerSummaries.GetAll();
            return View(summaries);
        }

    }

Comment: You should ask a new question.